# how find lower, higher values , given radius and height?

Tags: physics

One cubic centimeter of a typical cumulus cloud contains 50 to 500 water drops, which have a typical radius of 10 μm. For that range, give the lower value and the higher value, respectively, for the following.

(a) How many cubic meters of water are in a cylindrical cumulus cloud of height 2.1 km and radius 1.2 km?

(b) How many 1-liter pop bottles would that water fill?

(c) Water has a density of 1000 kg/m^3. How much mass does the water in the cloud have?

I don't understand what to do.

This is how the book explains a similar problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgXGX.png

I don't get how the (a) step works. I divided 50/9.4, but that's 5.3, not 4.7. Is the book wrong?